# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1) in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Hi I am trying to call async function `makeRemoteExecutableSchema` which returns promise.

```
async function run() {
  const schema = await makeRemoteExecutableSchema(
    createApolloFetch({
      uri: "https://5rrx10z19.lp.gql.zone/graphql"
    })
  );
}
```

I am calling this function in the constructor.

```
class HelloWorld {
  constructor() {
      try {
        run();
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e, e.message, e.stack);
      }
   }
}
```

I am getting this error. Does anyone know how to resolve this ?

```
(node:19168) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'getQueryType' of undefined
(node:19168) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Just a note: Generally, constructors should not be async or have such side effects: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24686979/1531054

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `makeRemoteExecutableScheme()` returns a promise that eventually rejects, then you have no code to handle that rejection.  You can handle it one of two ways:

```
async function run() {
  try {
      const schema = await makeRemoteExecutableSchema(
        createApolloFetch({
          uri: "https://5rrx10z19.lp.gql.zone/graphql"
        })
      );
   } catch(e) {
      // handle the rejection here
   }
}
```

Or here:

```
class HelloWorld {
  constructor() {
        run().catch(err => {
           // handle rejection here
        });
   }
}
```

You use `try/catch` around an `await` and within the same function.  One `run()` has returned, you're just dealing with a promise at that point so you would catch the rejection there with `.catch()`, not with `try/catch`.

---

It's important to remember that `await` is syntactical sugar for `.then()` within a function only.  It does not apply any magic beyond that function.  Once `run()` returns, it's just returning a regular promise so if you want to catch the rejection from that returned promise, you have to either use `.catch()` on it or `await` it again and then surround it with `try/catch`.  Surrounding a non-awaited promise with `try/catch` does not catch rejected promises which is what you were doing.